SonarLint can't find repository in Eclipse?
I'm unable to apply SonarLint in Eclipse. It is unable to find the git repository associated with the projects in my workspace.
I am able to update my repos with "Team", so I'm unsure why SonarLint cannot connect to the repos
Console log:
Using self-managed Java installation
Using JRE from C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.13.11-hotspot
Starting SonarLint for Eclipse 10.9.1.82333
SonarLint backend started, instance=org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.rpc.impl.SonarLintRpcServerImpl@196a42c3
Started embedded server on port 64120
Can't open directory channel. Log directory fsync won't be performed.
Node.js could not be automatically detected, has to be configured manually in the SonarLint preferences!
SonarLint processing file /projectFolder/com/projectComponent.java...
Git Repository not found for C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\projectFolder . The path C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\projectFolder is not in a Git repository

No file to analyze


Check Eclipse's Git configuration:
Window → Show View → Other → Git → Git Repositories
This will show which repositories Eclipse recognizes  , if you dont find your repo then click "Add an existing local Git repository"

@Mohamedaminebenhassen Thanks, I tried that, but it does not recognize my repos
I'm assuming this is because I cloned my repositories with SVN

SonarLint Eclipse only supports Git. Although it should not prevent you from using it, it only adds additional features.
